# Crash in nanopb iOS 17.4.0

Tags: ios, firebase, crash, exc-bad-access, nanopb

My app started crashing right on startup on iOS 17.4. Prior this version everything was ok. Crashlytics says this is some crash in `nanopb` on main thread in `pb_check_proto3_default_value + 342`.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000001736eb51c
```

[image]

As you can see, right in `AppDelegate`, `Firebase` starts its warming up routines (I guess) and crashes.

`nanopb` sources are cryptic for me because I don't know C.
The worst part the bug is reproducible only in Testflight builds, local builds (both release and debug) work well.

What can I do, guys? Maybe some of you experienced this problem on iOS 17.4 as well?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12442

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a bug in Firebase, which should be fixed in version 10.22.0.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11403

Comment: I was using CocoaPods and I had Firebase Crashlytics 10.20.0. Updating pod using `pod update FirebaseCrashlytics` to 10.22.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to jpa's answer of updating to Firebase 10.22.0, you can stick with Xcode 15.2 or earlier for previous Firebase versions.

The Xcode 15.3 release mode build exposes/introduces the coding issue in FirebaseSessions.